# Populate ReportViewer with a dynamic stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, stored-procedures, reportviewer

I need to fill a report with a stored procedure like this one:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].SelectDataToReport
     @table_name varchar (25),
     @period varchar (25)
AS
BEGIN
     DECLARE @mySql nvarchar (MAX)

     SET NOCOUNT ON;

     SET @mySql = 'SELECT * FROM '+@table_name+' WHERE Period = '+@period+''
     EXEC (@mySql)
END
```

But the report only accepts stored procedure like this one:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].SelectCSAT
     @Period varchar (25)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT ID, CSAT, Period
    FROM CSAT
    WHERE Period = @Period
END
```

So, I don't know if there's another way to fill the report. The thing is that the database tables and columns will be changed and when the report is generated, the user selects which table and period he wants.

I appreciate your help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267091/best-way-to-view-a-table-with-lots-of-columns/270576#270576

Answer (score 0):

all you have to do is do (if your column counts never vary, you cannot have dynamic columns)

(i do this all the time)

```
print @mySQL
```

1) Then take that statement and put it at the top of your stored procedure.
2) comment all your dynamic code out

3) go into ssrs and creating a data set will work.
4) go back into your stored procedure and comment out your sql statement and restore your dynamic code (dont forget to put back exec(@mySql)

for code example do this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].SelectDataToReport
 @table_name varchar (25),
 @period varchar (25)
AS
BEGIN
     SELECT ID , CSAT , Period FROM CSAT WHERE Period = '.'
 /*DECLARE @mySql nvarchar (MAX)

 SET NOCOUNT ON;

 SET @mySql = 'SELECT ID , CSAT , Period FROM '+@table_name+' WHERE Period = '+@period+''
 EXEC (@mySql)*/
END
```